# Knockout JS Radio buttons selecting last button if all values are true

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, radio-button

What I am trying to do is show some radio buttons with data from the server. The problem is that the checked value for the radio buttons can be all false and then KO automaticaly selects the last radio button just like in the JS fiddle that I have created below. This works perfectly as intended if one of the values is true but in my case there is a high chance that these values will all be false.

https://jsfiddle.net/9mtzbmng/1/

```
 self.addItems = function (items) {
            for (var x in items)
            {
                self.Items.push(new Item(items[x]));
            }
        }
    function Item(items) {
     this.ID = items.ID;
     this.Checked = ko.observable(false);
    }

 <input type="radio" data-bind="value: $data.ID,checked: Checked, checkedValue: Checked" name="items">
```

EDIT:
https://jsfiddle.net/hrhuym0u/
My issue was fixed after following this jsfiddle by setting the `checkedValue: 'true'` and setting `this.Checked = ko.observable("false")`!

Comment: Please make sure the question itself contains all code needed to repro the issue. If your [jsfiddle link rots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) the question will be rendered a lot less useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html):

> For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked if and only if the parameter value equals the radio button node’s ``value attribute or **the value specified by the `checkedValue` parameter**

In your case you need to set `checkedValue` to `true` so when your `Checked` observable contains `true` only then it checks your radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioB" data-bind="value: $data.ID, 
                                             checked: Checked, 
                                             checkedValue: true">
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/r6njzje3/

Note: if your radio buttons have the same `name` then they are forming a group so only one of them can be checked, that is way in your original sample always the last one is checked. Because the `checked` always equals with the value of `checkedValue`. So if you would remove the name `name="radioB"` all of your radios would be checked.

Note 2: You should make sure that you have actual `boolea`n values in your `Checked` properties and your server does not send them as strings e.g. `"true"`, because in this case you also need to specify the `checkedValue` as a string:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioB" data-bind="value: $data.ID, 
                                             checked: Checked, 
                                             checkedValue: 'true'">
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hrhuym0u/

Comment: problem is that now all are true so when i get data from server saying that one of them is true then no value is checked

Comment: Have you removed the name attribute? For me here is working fine with all true and all false: https://jsfiddle.net/7w2uvjqz/1/, Can you update this fiddle if it is still not working?

Comment: i have not removed the name atribute because i need them to act as a group this is why they have the same name in the jsfiddle i have made

Comment: OK, but then you should make sure that you get a real boolean from the server and not just the string `"true"`. Because if you have strings you need to have something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hrhuym0u/

Comment: thank you! managed to get this to work just right! I set it up like in your last js fiddle and it worked!